# Ubuntu 19.04 completely freezing every couple of hours

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell, freeze, 19.04

My Ubuntu 19.04 computer (it happened also with Ubuntu 18) freezes unexpectedly, the keyboard and mouse stop working and if I restart monitors they don't register any input. The only thing I can do is to press the power button for 5 seconds until it shuts down and then restart. I have dual-boot with Windows which works fine if that is somehow relevant.

Last time this happened this was logged each second for 2 minutes until it froze.

```
May 24 15:39:54 janpromainubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1819]: [18682:18753:0524/153954.992768:ERROR:latency_info.cc(147)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
May 24 15:39:55 janpromainubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1819]: [18682:18753:0524/153955.843148:ERROR:latency_info.cc(147)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
May 24 15:39:56 janpromainubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1819]: [18682:18753:0524/153956.693156:ERROR:latency_info.cc(147)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
May 24 15:39:57 janpromainubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1819]: [18682:18753:0524/153957.542491:ERROR:latency_info.cc(147)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
May 24 15:39:58 janpromainubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1819]: [18682:18753:0524/153958.393026:ERROR:latency_info.cc(147)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
May 24 15:39:59 janpromainubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1819]: [18682:18753:0524/153959.242858:ERROR:latency_info.cc(147)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
```

So I want to ask, what could be the problem and how to fix it?

```
janpro@janpromainubuntu:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       4,0Gi       6,1Gi        86Mi       5,6Gi        11Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
janpro@janpromainubuntu:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/janpro/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
janpro@janpromainubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8140996         0   8140996   0% /dev
tmpfs            1642044      2168   1639876   1% /run
/dev/sda6       76681304  14963504  57779536  21% /
tmpfs            8210216     72900   8137316   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8210216         0   8210216   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2          1024      1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop1          3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
/dev/loop3         82176     82176         0 100% /snap/audacity/288
/dev/loop4          4224      4224         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop5         55040     55040         0 100% /snap/core18/970
/dev/loop6         15104     15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/254
/dev/loop0         91392     91392         0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop8        154752    154752         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31
/dev/loop9        207232    207232         0 100% /snap/vlc/770
/dev/loop7          3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/81
/dev/loop10        82048     82048         0 100% /snap/audacity/211
/dev/loop11        36224     36224         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/nvme0n1p3     98304     35012     63292  36% /boot/efi
/dev/loop12        82176     82176         0 100% /snap/audacity/303
/dev/loop14       130048    130048         0 100% /snap/code/6
/dev/loop13        55040     55040         0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop15        90624     90624         0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop17          256       256         0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/4
/dev/loop16        15104     15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/258
/dev/loop18       130048    130048         0 100% /snap/code/7
/dev/loop19        91648     91648         0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop20       154752    154752         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40
/dev/loop21       224256    224256         0 100% /snap/gimp/165
tmpfs            1642040        60   1641980   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p4 468220924 144910160 323310764  31% /media/janpro/M2SSD
```

Comment: A number of things can cause similar symptoms. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `df`.

Comment: Do you have a Bay Trail or Cherry Trail CPU from Intel?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix no I have Ryzen 1600

Answer (score 0):

may not be just 19.04 my 18.04 just became unstable as well , my multi-display screens go black and primary screen stays on but everything is locked up

this system normally runs months at a time no issues 
I have had to force reboot it a dozen times today , ever since I let it do a reboot as their had been quite a lot of updates that had been applied over the months .. it was running kernel 5.1 for some time so i do not think it was that ..

i7-4790K CPU

random errors in syslog this would have been last error before reboot

cma_alloc: alloc failed